# Getting count of data with same place and displaying it in TextView

Tags: android, mysql

I actually have 2 questions. Im doing this android app in which user enters logs. In layout i have list grouped by places and I need to show count of all logs for that place.
This is my code for grouping places

```
public ArrayList<Logs> getAllLogsGroupedByPlace() {
        ArrayList<Logs> logByPlaceList = new ArrayList<Logs>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " GROUP BY " + KEY_PLACE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Logs log = new Logs();
                log.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                log.setCreatedAt(cursor.getString(1));
                log.setPlace(cursor.getString(2));
                logByPlaceList.add(log);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return logByPlaceList;
    }
```

And this is my code for Counting logs by place

```
public int getLogsCountPlace() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " WHERE " + KEY_PLACE + "=" + KEY_PLACE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

So my Question is how properly count these log grouped by place and then display them in my lists textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your getLogsCountPlace method.

```
public Map<String,Integer> getLogsCountPlace() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*), " + KEY_PLACE + " FROM " + TABLE_LOGS + " GROUP BY " + KEY_PLACE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        //// The cursor will return 2 columns, the first column will have the count of each place and the second column will have the place name. You could store the counts in a Map, having the place as the key and the count as the value.
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: Ok I got it. But how call that now in activity and place it into TextView?

Comment: Just iterate over the cursor and append the column values, then set it to the TextView.